# Multiple contexts and MergeOption

Tags: entity-framework

Setting MergeOption on an EntitySet overrides the caching behavior of all subsequent queries on that EntitySet -- that's clear.

However, it seems like setting MergeOption on an EntitySet for one context also affects the caching behavior of all queries on *other* contexts...

Example:

```
using (var db1 = new context()) {
    db1.Table.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTrack;

    using (var db2 = new context()) {
        var record = db2.Table.FirstOrDefault();
        // record is *detached*
    }
}
```

The only way to get another caching behavior on db2 is to convert the query into an ObjectQuery and then change the query's MergeOption.  I use the following very handy extension method:

```
public static ObjectResult<T> WithMergeOption<T> (this IQueryable<T> query, MergeOption mergeoption)
{
    return (query as ObjectQuery<T>).Execute(mergeoption);
}
```

Is this expected behavior for an EntitySet's MergeOption?  It almost behaves as if it overrides a static default instead of a default on the context instance.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `EntityState` is `Unchanged`.

Comment: Strange...  Could it be that I am using EF 6?